# Why do Dan and Sandy kiss each other?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-man-from-earth

In the last scene of *The Man from Earth* - when all of the guests leave the house except for Will and Dan - John and Sandy are standing on the porch talking. Dan comes out and bids them both farewell, and then he kisses Sandy on the mouth. Can someone explain why?

Earlier in the movie, Sandy told John that she loves him. Why would she then kiss Dan on the mouth? Or was it just a mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe it's a mistake, I just don't believe it's as significant a scene as you think. They say goodbye at the end of the party and Dan goes to leave. He kisses her goodbye and she kisses him in return.

There's nothing I can see in the kiss that I consider sexual. I myself have occasionally kissed, or been kissed, at the end of a night by friends like that.

So to answer your question, in my view it's not a romantic kiss and it *certainly* doesn't indicate Sandy loves Dan instead of John. Rather, it's more of a heartwarming "peck" - a display of gratitude and solidarity at the incredible evening they've both had, and a sign of their friendship.

Comment: Maybe I am giving too much significance. It just seemed weird at the moment.

Comment: Actually you're not the only one bothered by this. I'm not sure in which part of the world, a straight man and a straight woman will kiss each other unless there's some romantic connection between them, or they're just being silly, or they're drunk. None of these are true, hence I wonder. So I find this odd too.

Besides, something else is odd: Sandy, who's in love with John, is in love with John, but she arrives with Edith and Harry, exiting their care at 1:00 of the movie. How come wasn't she already present with John? Also, I never saw them kissing (contd to the next comment)

Comment: @KarxMarl (contd from the last comment) though she leaned her head on John's shoulder when they were alone. But kissing Dan instead of John, nope sorry can't take it. Andrew Martin must be having really good, not romantically involved, female friends who kiss him on the mouth :)